# Proving a flow of a dynamical system is complete

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to prove that the flow (defined as a mapping from R^n to R^n) of a dynamical system (a R^n system with first order derivatives) is complete.  However I am stuck after I have proven that a bounded C^1 function proves any solution exists on a finite (compact?) interval of time.

My attempt ('proof'):

Since the derivative(*) (1st order) is bounded (and this is a dynamical system governed by first order derivatives), then we can see that any solution is bounded toa finite interval of time.  Since the solution is bounded and defined on some interval, say (-c, c) we can see that the flow exists and since it exists on the inerval, then it is complete (defined?)

(*) |dG/dx| < cG

I still feel my proof is very inadequate.

EDIT: General system dx/dt = v(x) (in R^n.)  In addition it satisfies |v(x)| <= |x|c1 + c2.  I have shown that this is true because I showed that the derivative (1st order) is bounded by a function and a constant...

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the problem. First, for a flow to be “complete” means it is defined everywhere, doesn't it? Which means the solution does not blow up in finite time. Second, it is not clear what is assumed about the right hand side in the system. And what is $G$ here? I thought maybe it is the right hand side of the system, i.e., the system is $\dot x=G(x)$, but it is not at all clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi In this case G(x) = |x|^2 + 1.  The system (sorry I am new to this forum) dx/dt = v(x) and it needs to satisfy |v(x)| <= c1 + c2|x|.  Since I have proven (using G(x) as an arbitrary example) that the solution is bounded on a finite time interval, then I can conclude (that on an interval (-c, c) it the flow exists and thus is complete?)  In addition as a first note in my train of thought.  Since a bounded derivative is continuos, then in this case (since G(x) is continuous) then the flow is defined since it does not blow up...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that any solution can be extended to all $t$. By a basic theorem on dynamical systems, if that is not so, then $|x|\to\infty$ either as $t\to t0$ for some time $t_0$, approaching either from the left or from the right.

Concentrate on the first case, i.e., you are looking at the solution as $t$ increases. Estimate $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigl|e^{-ct}x(t)\bigr|$$ where $c$ is any constant with $c>c_2$. You will find that the derivative is negative if $|x|$ is large, so $\bigl|e^{-ct}x(t)\bigr|$ cannot go to infinity at any finite time, and hence neither can $|x|$. I am leaving the details for you to work out. But note that for any vector function $y$, the derivative of $|y|$ is $y\cdot\dot y/|y|$, where $\dot y=dy/dt$.

Comment: If what I understand by your post.  A good theorem to use would be "The Picard Existence Thoerem?"

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I am at work so I cannot go through it in depth.  But my general train of thought is to use the Picard Thoerem to prove that the solution is unique and it thus satisfies the Dynamical System.  Since the flow is the trajectory (behavior) of the solution it also satisfies the dynamical system and thus the flow is complete.